# Changing modal content based on trigger button - Title and video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How do I change the video and title of a modal based on what link was pressed?

The src I want to change based on the link pressed is here.

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src=" Link's URL here " allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The title is here.

```
<h4 class="modal-title" id="tutorial-modal"> Link's title here </h4>
```

The buttons are written like so.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorial-modal" data-title=" The title for this link " data-video=" URL For the video for this link ">
```

I'm trying to take the data-title=" " and the data-video=" " and replace the modal's title and iframe src=" " with these respectively. Thank you!

*I have more than one modal on my page, all different, I only want to change the content on tutorial-modal based on the link clicked.*

Comment: try using jquery .attr() to get and set attribute of your element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements should have unique IDs. Since you have multiple buttons, you might want to use just a class there.

This can be done is plain Javascript, but since you have jQuery tagged, I will answer with that.

First you need a click event:

```
$(".my_button").on('click', function(){

})
```

Then you need to target the elements you want

```
$("#my_h4")
$("#my_iframe")
```

And lastly assign value

```
$(".my_button").on('click', function(){
    $("#my_h4").text( 
        $(this).attr("data-title") 
    );

    $("#my_iframe").attr(
        "src",
        $(this).attr("data-video") 
    );
})
```

Where `this` refers to the context of the `click` event, which is the `$(".my_button")` that was clicked.

Comment: I ended up using IDs for each button as they trigger their own unique Title and video for the modal. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can append click events to all links, read the current link data and update the title and the iframe's video source.

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  var title = $(this).attr("data-title"),
      src = $(this).attr("data-video");

  $("#tutorial-modal").html(title);   
  $("iframe").attr('src', src); 

})
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/petjofi/Lmr2he7u/